# Build/deploy javafx android Application error

Tags: java, android, javafx, gluon-mobile

i'm following a tutorial from youtube... Everything is fine, till the moment i double click on "android" at the Gradle Task to build the apk... At first i was Getting the following error:

**Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip'.**
I have everything installed(sdk, gradle...)

And now i;m getting this:

**Configured compileSdkVersion is invalid: 21 (C:/Users/Hayden/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/platforms/android-21**

**Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip'.**

Thanks in advance!

** Gradle **

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.0.0-b10'
}
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
jcenter()
}

mainClassName = 'com.twentyOneStudios.FxApplication'

jfxmobile {
android {
    manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
    androidSdk = 'C:/Users/Hayden/AppData/Local/Android/sdk'
}
}
```

The IDE is e(fx)clipse 4.5 Mars.

Comment: Are you using JavaFXPorts? Are you using the Gluon plugin?  Post more details (build.gradle, IDE, what you have installed...), as it is hard to tell otherwise

Comment: You can edit your question and post it there. You are using a very old version of the jfxmobile plugin. I suggest you install the Gluon plugin for Eclipse, it will generate a project with the latest version

Comment: Sorry my mistake on editing the question... Could youn poibt me out on how to fix this?? Because i installed the repositore from gluon site i guess... [this](http://gluonhq.com/the-new-gluon-plugin-for-eclipse/) Sorry my dumbness @JoséPereda

Comment: Install the Gluon [plugin](http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/4.0.1/#eclipse-plugin) for Eclipse, then follow the instructions to create a first project. Also check prerequisites [here](http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/4.0.1/#_android). See samples using the plugin [here](http://gluonhq.com/support/samples/).

Comment: Thanks... I have download the dalvik... But i dont have any folder named "arm" on jdk instalation...And now when i try to instal the gluon plugin it says "Cannot perform operation. Computing..."